# Migrate Chart Web Part from SP 2007 to O365

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2007, migration, data-view-web-part, chart-web-part

I am doing sharepoint migration from 2007 to O365. I have chart web part in 2007 which is exactly in this link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc300164(v=office.12).aspx

I want migrate this web part to O365. I did the following steps:

1. Export from SP 2007.
2. Replace the list ID in webpart file with new list id in O365.
3. import into O365.

Now I can see the web part in O365, but status count, percentage and chart bar is not correct. Everything is zero. Looking for best practice to make this. Thanks for your response in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the best practice I would definatly recommond looking for a Javascript solution.There many tutorials available on how to do this.

You could think about creating a html file, use it in a Content Editor Webpart, loading the data through rest and displaying it with a javascript chart library.

One example of a chart:
http://blog.appliedis.com/2014/07/29/transform-your-sharepoint-list-data-into-an-eye-catching-chart/

And if you are really looking for a SharePoint way to do this using JSLink and respecting a the Minimal Download strategy, read this post from a SharePoint MCM:
http://yuriburger.net/2015/08/03/a-worldmap-list-visualization-for-sharepoint-online/

Comment: These strategies do not directly address the question how do I migrate a web part from 2007 to O365. I think this answer is partially correct because there has been a strategy shift in web parts between SP 2007 and O365.  I would not recommend trying to migrate the web part as the question states, but would recommend a js solution to handle it on render or with a calculated column with image tags.

Comment: You are right, in my answer I focused on *looking for the best practice to make this*. And the practice from 2007 is considered something you should avoid.